# RedirectToAction by using Request.UrlReferrer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, response.redirect

Excuse me if it is a duplicate but I am trying to find the best way to go back to previous page, while I do server side validation on my controller.

I tried some things, which are probably bad practices...

```
Response.Redirect("~" + Request.UrlReferrer.LocalPath);
```

this raises an issue with AntiForgery Token.

Also:

```
RedirectToRoute(Request.UrlReferrer.LocalPath);
```

raised:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
>   client (:).

And some other things that did not work.

I need some suggestion that makes use of the `Request.UrlReferrer` and does not need any extra additions to my Views or ViewModels, please

**EDIT:**
From what I searched so far, the best way wold be to use

```
return RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues);
```

But how can I get the parameter values for this `(string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)` by utilizing the `Request.UrlReferrer` object???

Comment: Be warned about using the UrlReferrer in general. It might not be set to what you expect.

Comment: @Mattias, thank you for the warning! I would appreciate a suggestion along.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/163532). More likely than not, you want to take a user to a page to perform some action and then redirect them back to the page they originally came from. The correct way to do that is to send them to the page where they must perform an action with a return URL in the query string:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Foo", new { returnUrl = Request.RawUrl })">Do something</a>
```

Then, on the form for that page, you add:

```
@Url.Hidden("returnUrl", Request["returnUrl"])
```

Finally, in your post action:

```
public ActionResult Foo (MyModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do something

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Fallback");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

`UrlReferrer` is dangerous to use because 1) it's not guaranteed to be present at all and 2) even if it is, the value can be trivially spoofed.